# How to compile EnergyPlus to WASM (WebAssembly) with Emscripten?

Tags: cmake, webassembly, emscripten, energyplus

I wanted to compile EnergyPlus (https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus) to a WASM module.

These are steps I followed:

1. Installed **Emscripton** on system. `emcc --check` produces the output

```
emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement + linker emulating GNU ld) 3.1.37-git
shared:INFO: (Emscripten: Running sanity checks)
```

2. Cloned the **EnergyPlus** from GitHub `git clone https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus`
3. `cd EnergyPlus`
4. `mkdir build`
5. `cd build`
6. `emcmake cmake ..`
   This gave the error

```
-- Using X11 for window creation
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_LIB)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindX11.cmake:481 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  third_party/penumbra/vendor/glfw/CMakeLists.txt:196 (find_package)
```

Since the **EnergyPlus** (https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus) project is using **Cmake** as the build system, I followed the section [Integrating with a build system](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#integrating-with-a-build-system) from the official documentation of **Emscripton**.

If `emcmake cmake ..` succeeds, I would be able to run `emcc [-Ox] project.o -o project.js` and this would generate the WASM (WebAssembly) module?

**Update**: For step 6, instead of using `cmake .. -DGLFW_USE_OSMESA=1 -DBUILD_STATIC_ENERGYPLUS_API=1` gets rid of the previous error and instead the error I get now is,

```
CMake Error in src/EnergyPlus/CMakeLists.txt:
  export called with target "energyplusapi" which requires target
  "energypluslib" that is not in any export set.


CMake Error in src/EnergyPlus/CMakeLists.txt:
  export called with target "energyplusapi" which requires target
  "project_options" that is not in any export set.


CMake Error in src/EnergyPlus/CMakeLists.txt:
  export called with target "energyplusapi" which requires target
  "project_fp_options" that is not in any export set.


CMake Error in src/EnergyPlus/CMakeLists.txt:
  export called with target "energyplusapi" which requires target
  "project_warnings" that is not in any export set.
```

Comment: related: https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus/search?l=CMake&q=find_package+X11 and https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus/search?l=CMake&q=_GLFW_X11 in particular, "`elseif (UNIX) set(_GLFW_X11 1)`", then see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/UNIX.html. I'm not sure, but this might boil down to modifying those files to make it more Emscripten-friendly.

Comment: your new problem just sounds like a bug with the CMake config of that project. I'd encourage you to raise a bug report to the maintainers. That's the best way to get the problem fixed once and for all. If you do, please add a link here to that bug ticket for posterity.

Comment: Yes, I just opened an issue on GitHub. Here it is https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus/issues/9997